# Upload folder from sourcetree to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to upload a bootstrap folder into bitbucket using sourcetree, but it doesn't recognize my folder when I copy it onto my local repository. I can create simple text files that are noticed, but Sourcetree doesn't respond to the folder.

Comment: Do you have a `.gitignore` file?

Comment: how do i check?

Comment: Is there a file called `.gitignore` in your repository? If yes check if the bootstrap folder is listed in there. Additionally you could post your git status to see what's happening

Answer (score 1):

Git does not track empty directories. If that is what you were trying to do, consider this question: [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a .gitignore file inside that directory that contains these two lines:

`*
!.gitignore`